# Hide the selection outline after selecting a new tab

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, outline

I am using bootstrap and I am annoyed by the tiny outline that appears around the tab link, after each tab is selected. Is there any way to remove it?

I tried using the trick below, but it did not help

```
a:active {
    outline: none;
}
```

Left image is what I get. Right image is what is should be.

[image]
[image]

Comment: if a:focus doesn't works too, try   <a  class="active" hidefocus="true">

Comment: Maybe using !important; ?

Comment: @Andrew `border` or `outline` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for the whole page

```
html * {
 outline: 0 !important;
}
```